# Not able to plot location on map as a turn-key system

Tags: javascript, delphi, google-maps-api-3, delphi-2010

I have a simple custom browser that displays a google map that works fine.  What I want to do is make it a turn key form that shows the location of an individual when it opens and plots it on a map.

This is a little test program to prove the concept.

If I add the location by displaying the form and adding the values to edit boxes and running the ButtonGotoLocation procedure, it works every time.

If I set this up as a turn-key system, i.e. calling the  `HTMLWindow2.execScript(Format('GotoLatLng(%s,%s)',['34','-84.00']), 'JavaScript');`

I have even tried creating the form and showing it and then calling a procedure from the calling form.  Same result;

Is this a weird concurrency issue?  That is why I used an external procedure but to no avail.

```
unit uStreetMap;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, OleCtrls, SHDocVw, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, XPMan, ComCtrls,MSHTML;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    LabelAddress: TLabel;
    PanelHeader: TPanel;
    ButtonGotoLocation: TButton;
    XPManifest1: TXPManifest;
    MemoAddress: TMemo;
    ButtonGotoAddress: TButton;
    LabelLatitude: TLabel;
    LabelLongitude: TLabel;
    Longitude: TEdit;
    Latitude: TEdit;
    ButtonClearMarkers: TButton;

    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ButtonGotoAddressClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ButtonGotoLocationClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ButtonClearMarkersClick(Sender: TObject);

    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    HTMLWindow2: IHTMLWindow2;
    function UTCToSystemTime(UTC: TDateTime): TDateTime;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation

uses
   ActiveX, DateUtils;


{$R *.dfm}

const
HTMLStr: AnsiString =
'<html> '+
'<head> '+
'<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" /> '+
'<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.24&amp;libraries=geometry"></script> '+
'<script type="text/javascript"> '+
''+
''+
'  var geocoder; '+
'  var map;  '+
'  var markersArray = [];'+
''+
''+
'  function initialize() { '+
'    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();'+
'    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.714776,-74.019213); '+
'    var myOptions = { '+
'      zoom: 13, '+
'      center: latlng, '+
'      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP '+
'    }; '+
'    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); '+
'    map.set("streetViewControl", false);'+
'  } '+
''+
''+
'  function codeAddress(address) { '+
'    if (geocoder) {'+
'      geocoder.geocode( { address: address}, function(results, status) { '+
'        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {'+
'          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);'+
'          PutMarker(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng(), results[0].geometry.location.lat()+","+results[0].geometry.location.lng());'+
'        } else {'+
'          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);'+
'        }'+
'      });'+
'    }'+
'  }'+
''+
''+
'  function GotoLatLng(Lat, Lang) { '+
'   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lang);'+
'   map.setCenter(latlng);'+
'   PutMarker(Lat, Lang, Lat+","+Lang);'+
'  }'+
''+
''+
'function ClearMarkers() {  '+
'  if (markersArray) {        '+
'    for (i in markersArray) {  '+
'      markersArray[i].setMap(null); '+
'    } '+
'  } '+
'}  '+
''+
'  function PutMarker(Lat, Lang, Msg) { '+
'   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lang);'+
'   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'+
'      position: latlng, '+
'      map: map,'+
'      title: Msg+" ("+Lat+","+Lang+")"'+
'  });'+
' markersArray.push(marker); '+
'  }'+
''+
''+
''+'</script> '+
'</head> '+
'<body onload="initialize()"> '+
'  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div> '+
'</body> '+
'</html> ';
```

This causes an exception as Script Error 'GotoLatLng' is undefined

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   HTMLWindow2.execScript(Format('GotoLatLng(%s,%s)',['34.00','-84.00']), 'JavaScript');
end;
```

constructor

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  aStream     : TMemoryStream;
begin
   WebBrowser1.Navigate('about:blank');
    if Assigned(WebBrowser1.Document) then
    begin
      aStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
         aStream.WriteBuffer(Pointer(HTMLStr)^, Length(HTMLStr));
         aStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
         (WebBrowser1.Document as IPersistStreamInit).Load(TStreamAdapter.Create(aStream));
      finally
         aStream.Free;
      end;
      HTMLWindow2 := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).parentWindow;

    end;
end;
```

Using this procedure works fine.  I enter the Lat/Lng in the text box and click the button and all is well.

```
procedure TfrmMain.ButtonGotoLocationClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   HTMLWindow2.execScript(Format('GotoLatLng(%s,%s)',[Latitude.Text,Longitude.Text]), 'JavaScript');
end;
```

but if I try to make the form display the location on the map (as turn key), I get the error.

```
procedure TfrmMain.ButtonClearMarkersClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HTMLWindow2.execScript('ClearMarkers()', 'JavaScript')
end;

procedure TfrmMain.ButtonGotoAddressClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   address    : string;
begin
   address := MemoAddress.Lines.Text;
   address := StringReplace(StringReplace(Trim(address), #13, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]), #10, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]);
   HTMLWindow2.execScript(Format('codeAddress(%s)',[QuotedStr(address)]), 'JavaScript');
end;


end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is what I did.  I threw a TTimer on the form to execute the script to call the GotoLatLng.  Since I could not find a handle to use signal a WaitForSingleObject, this was the best I could do.  I set it as 1700 ms and it seems to be enough time.
I also moved the Map creation out of the unit constructor and into the Form Constructor.

It's all good.